# Real-Time Server to Client Using SignalR

Tags: asp.net, signalr, real-time

Let me explain my application so that i can put the reader into the picture of what i am actually doing.

I am using MVC5 with signalR for a web application.

The application consists of a client to server connection. On the other hand the server also has a controller which connects to a PLC (Programmable Logic Controller) it is a simple hardware controller with hardware IOs.

I am using SignalR to write to the plc as follows:
Client (JS) -> SignalRHub -> MVC Controller -> PLC

I also need that the server broadcasts when there is a change in the PLC as Follows:
PLC -> MVC Controller -> SignalRHub -> Client.

The MVC Controller has an event that when there is a change on the plc it is fired.

The problem is that when the client connects ok it does create an instance of the SignalRHub but when it is ready the Hub is destroyed so if there is a change on the PLC it is completely lost and cannot be pushed to the client.

The client Code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
    console.log(chat);

    chat.client.writeMessage = function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }

    var i = $.connection.hub.start().then(function (event) {
        $('#send').click(function () {
            console.log("clicked");
            chat.server.plcWrite(true);
        });
    });
});
```

Which means (as i understand) on document ready create the hub connection and also when the button #send is clicked write to the plc which works perfectly fine.

This is the Hub code:

```
Controllers.PlcController plc = new Controllers.PlcController();
//public void bMessage()
//{
    // Clients.All.writeMessage(x);
// }


public void plcWrite(bool write)
{
    plc.plcWritebool(write);
    plc._broadcast += plc__broadcast;
}

void plc__broadcast(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool s = plc.plcRead();

    Clients.All.broadcast(s);
}
```

The problem that i am reading into is that when the client clicks the button it creates always a new controller and is lost when ready.

Does anyone have any idea so that to keep the hub always the same one and always stay connected with my controller? Hope the explanation is clear if you need any more information please don't hesitate to ask!

**Edit:** I know i can do with a polling frequency from the client side but it will create alot of traffic and more i have to access the plc every poll which is not that flexible. Its better to update the client when the plc has a change!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have way to much coupling to Core logic from hub and MVC controller.

Both a MVC controller and a HUB has a request life time, trying to make them keep data longer than that using static collections etc is not good practice.

If the PLC controller code is long running it should not be called from the Controller or HUB at all, instead in the HUB or controller put it in a queue. Have a ASP.NET background worker pick the job up. Process it there. I would then use some kind of low foot print Service bus or event aggregator publish the states. Have SignalR listening to these states either with your own library or you can use this library if you want (Disclaimer, I'm the author).

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki

Read up on ASP.NET background workers here
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-long-background-process-in-asp-net.aspx

You can also create a windows service for your Background stuff and use a Service bus to signal my library. For example Rabbit MQ etc

Comment: Let me see if i did understand... So you library generates an event listener and each time the background worker fires the event (for example when i get a change on the plc) the client event is also fired and i can update the client as i need right?
In other words i can work with just a background worker and no need to use an MVC?

Comment: Yes, you will need to start your job somehow offcouse, either through a Hub or WebAPI controller or MVC Controller (Though WebAPI have replaced MVC controller for REST stuff). After that your background worker will publish states on your bus and my library will forward them seamless to all or concerned clients (It has a built in API for constraints)

Comment: thanks i will try to make the most of your library and will let you know about it.
The only problem is where to start the worker so that i will always be in the same scope.

Comment: It is giving me a error on `app.MapEventProxy<EventBase>();` and `RouteTable.Routes.MapEventProxy<EventBase>();` saying that i am missing a directive
Do you have a solution on how to use your library? I mean more detailed in than the documentation... Sorry but i am new to this type of programming

Comment: RouteTable.Routes.MapEventProxy<EventBase>(); Is SignalR 1.x code you should use the first Syntax.  app.MapEventProxy<EventBase>();

Comment: Also look at the Demo project here https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/tree/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Demo.MVC4

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question, but I'm facing a very similar problem (even down to interacting with a PLC - actually a FPGA in my case). I've tried reading about the EventAggregatorProxy library but I'm having a hard time getting my head around where it fits in to the architecture!

I was instead considering the approach detailed [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub). This involves reversing the dependency, so in your case the PlcController would reference the Hub, perhaps something like this:-

```
public class PlcController
{
    IHubContext _hubContext;

    public PlcController()
    {
        _hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyPlcHub>();
    }
}
```

After reading the PLC you would broadcast the result using this syntax:

```
_hubContext.Clients.All.broadcast(s);
```

Did you end up using the EventAggregatorProxy library in your solution?